# Converting sound to waveform with customisation options

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, playback

I’m looking for libraries (or good tutorials) allowing me to convert a song to a waveform format. 
Bonus features I'm looking for:
1.  Alter the colors of waves, width, spacing etc.
2.  Trim the song to length decided by the user

I’ve found quite a lot libraries creating sound DYNAMICALLY to the waveform, however, it’s hard to find anything that converts the entire song a tonce and allows customization.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of libraries like this. In particular there are some of them that provides a custom rendering feature, like

https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/ (look at the end of the page).

There is a method to change the color of the waveform and trimming is matter of linear proportion `(canvas.width : songTotalSeconds = myCutLine.x : cutAtTime)`, so you can resolve it with a custom renderer and nothing else.

EDIT: There is also a [CURSOR example](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/cursor/index.html) that fits your needs